# Camera intent filter

Tags: android, camera, intentfilter

I need some help on camera intent / filter. Below are my questions.

- What is the intent filter I should use to make my app handle camera intent ?
- Are there any apps which handles a camera intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) ?

What I am trying to figure out is, if I through an intent with filter ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, is it possible for any 3rd party app to respond for my request?

Any help is  appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. What is the intent filter I should use to make my app handle camera intent ?**

Ans)  should be included in the manifest file intent-filter of the activity which can handle a camera

**2. Are there any apps which handles a camera intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) ?**

Ans)Pudding Camera, LINE Camera, Uva silent camera Free,..

I got confused because intent used to call camera app is android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE and intent-filter used in manifest file is android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE.

Thanks for all who replied.

Thanks,

Sai.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to the manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

As for apps, there are plenty of apps that handle the intents. Just search for "Camera" on the Play Store. Here's the one of Google:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

2:

Yes, any app can respond to the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. Don't know if you have more than 1 on your device but you can easily try out. (fire the intent)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two ore more apps installed that can handle the intent, the system will prompt you automatically which to use. If you need some code to handle the results let me know.