# Can I change the "type" of an App? e.g. if I wanted to make a Barcode Scanner my default "Camera" app... could I do that?

Tags: android, android-camera

The TL;DR is I want to upload photos to a web form that aren't purely photos. In this specific case it would be an image from a Thermal Camera App that has its own physical accessory.

So [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtvMw.jpg) would list the Thermal Cam app as well.

Currently I cannot set it as the "Default Camera" application even though it does take pictures. Can I do anything to change that?

I am speaking as a tech-savvy user making educated guesses, not a developer.

Phone is a Samsung J7, Version 7.1.1 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

The app needs to support the [Camera Intent Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12373075/295004) which would require the app developer to support all of the ways to pass back an image.

**What can you do**

Ask the publisher/developer of *Thermal Camera App* to support Camera Intents.